# Cannot open backup device 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\DBBackupMyDatabaseName 21-12-2016.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to take backup of my db programmatically. The scenario is that user will click backup button and a FolderBrowserDialog will be opened up where the user can create new folder or select an existing folder and then press ok to create a .bak file in that target folder/destination. I have written the following code but getting the Access denied (see the title of the question) error and I am unable to figure out the problem. I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2014.
Here is the code:

```
Private Sub DbBackupButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DbBackupButton.Click
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            Dim DatabaseName As String = "MyDatabaseName"
            Dim DestinationPath As String = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "MyDatabaseName" & DateTime.Now.Day & "-" & DateTime.Now.Month & "-" & DateTime.Now.Year & ".bak"
            backupDB(DatabaseName, DestinationPath)

        Catch ex As ApplicationException
            MsgBox("ERROR" & ex.Message, "ERROR")

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
 Private Sub backupDB(ByVal DatabaseName As String, ByVal DestinationPath As String)
    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbx").ConnectionString
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)


        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE @DatabaseName TO DISK = @DestinationPath", conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatabaseName", DatabaseName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DestinationPath", DestinationPath)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Backup Generated Succesfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)


        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Can anybody figure out the problem and its solution Please? Thanks

Comment: add user permition

Comment: DBBackupMyDatabaseName 21-12-2016.bak' add user full permition

Comment: The database engine runs under another user, for example sql 2016 username is mssql$my_instance_name, this user should have read permission. Backup to user's Desktop, located in user profile is not very good idea, usually user profile has no access for other users, but if you want exactly desktop, add read/write access to mssql user to your  user profile ("c:\users\pc")

Comment: @vitalygolub i have selected Drive D and the code executed successfully without any access denied error but when i checked that folder in D drive which was target folder there was nothing in there. What could be the problem?

Comment: Looks, like you concatenate selectedpath with filename without backslash, your file is somewhere in another place d:\yourpathMydataBaseName-12-16.bak instead of d:\yourpath\MydataBaseName-12-16.bak instead

Comment: yeah found it. its in D drive but i want to add it to the selected folder. would you please tell me how to correct if there is something missing in my code so that the backup can be taken in the selected folder in D drive? @vitalygolub

Comment: @omer  add backslash `FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "\MyDatabaseName" &`

Comment: @vitalygolub Works Like a Magic. Cheers mate.